# Use Functions to get total number of in-progress and ringing calls to number

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

Am familiar with Twilio Studio and Twilio API (via PHP). Not familiar with Functions/node, so I'm a little lost on how to do this simple requirement...

In Studio I need to call a Function to return an integer of the total number of 'in-progress' and 'ringing' calls to a specific phone number (added together).

For example, if there are 7 'in-progress' and 5 'ringing' the function would return 12.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Functions allow you to run JavaScript in response to an HTTP request (or request from Studio). You can read about [how Functions work in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation). To fetch the calls and filter them by their current status, you would use the [Call Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource). There are examples in the [documentation for fetching calls and filtering and all the documentation has examples in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-read-multiple-call-resources-and-filter-by-call-status-and-phone-number&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x), as well as PHP so you can compare.

Here's a Function I put together quickly (I haven't tested it, but I think it looks good). It fetches the calls that are ringing and in-progress, and returns an object with individual totals and a total. You can then use this in your widget and refer to the values with variables like `{{widgets.FUNCTION_WIDGET_NAME.parsed.ringing}}`.

```js
exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  const ringingPromise = client.calls.list({ status: 'ringing' });
  const inProgressPromise = client.calls.list({ status: 'in-progress' });

  const [ringing, inProgress] = await Promise.all([ringingPromise, inProgressPromise]);
  const response = {
    ringing: ringing.length,
    inProgress: inProgress.length,
    total: ringing.length + inProgress.length
  };
  callback(null, response);
}
```